# Elevation of child view is wrong when animating scale

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a view with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.myapp.views.ContextMenu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_container_background"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            tools:itemCount="6"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_context_menu_item"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</com.myapp.views.ContextMenu>
```

And I want the menu to appear using this animation

```
public void startShowAnimation() {
    setScaleX(.2f);
    setScaleY(.2f);
    setAlpha(0f);
    animate()
        .scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f)
        .alpha(1f)
        .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
        .setDuration(SHOW_ANIMATION_DURATION)
        .start();
}
```

But when the view animates, the shadow under menuBackground starts out big, like it would be if the view has 20% scale, then it scales up with the shadow and once the animation is over, the shadow jumps to the proper size.

When the animation starts it looks like this:

[image: animation start]

Then when it is almost done the shadow is out of proportion:

[image: animation 75%]

When the animation is done the shadow gets smaller suddenly:

[image: animation done]

How do I make sure the animation doesn't affect the child's shadow?